# MassTransit: Avoid pushing to RabbitMQ when receiving messages via Kafka

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am running an application that acts as a consumer for messages via RabbitMQ and Kafka. It does not produce anything. While the application works, I notice that the messages received via Kafka are also pushed into RabbitMQ. Can this be avoided? Can I configure MassTransit, that Kafka messages are not pushed to RabbitMQ?

Here is my current setup

```cs
if (!options.RabbitMq.Enabled) 
    return;

busConfigurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
busConfigurator.AddConsumer<RabbitMqConsumer, RabbitMqConsumerDefinition>();
busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, busFactoryConfigurator) =>
{
    busFactoryConfigurator.Host(new Uri(options.RabbitMq.Endpoint));
    busFactoryConfigurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

```cs
if (!options.Kafka.Enabled) 
   return;
        
var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig
{
    Url = options.Kafka.SchemaRegistryUrl
};
var schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig);
busConfigurator.AddSingleton<ISchemaRegistryClient>(schemaRegistryClient);
        
busConfigurator.AddRider(rider =>
{
    rider.AddConsumer<KafkaMyMessageConsumer>();
    rider.UsingKafka((context, kafkaConfigurator) =>
    {
        kafkaConfigurator.ClientId = options.Kafka.ClientId;
        kafkaConfigurator.Host(options.Kafka.Endpoint, configureHost =>
        {
           // ssl, sasl configuration
        });
        kafkaConfigurator.TopicEndpoint<string, MyMessage>(options.Kafka.Topic, options.Kafka.GroupId, endpointConfigurator =>
        {
           endpointConfigurator.CreateIfMissing(t => t.NumPartitions = 1);
           endpointConfigurator.SetValueDeserializer(new ProtobufDeserializer<MyMessage>().AsSyncOverAsync());
           endpointConfigurator.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
           endpointConfigurator.ConfigureConsumer<KafkaMyMessageConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT:
Why I am confused about RabbitMQ & Kafka, i see the following log messages

```
2023-12-20 23:19:51 [22:19:51 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://my-rabbitmq/kafka/my-kafka-topic/my-service 
2023-12-20 23:19:51 [22:19:51 INF] Bus started: rabbitmq://my-rabbitmq/ 
2023-12-20 23:19:51 [22:19:51 DBG] Partition: my-kafka-topic [[0]] with -1001 was assigned to: my-service-e470f4c3-4581-4a7d-8787-591389c2150b 
2023-12-20 23:19:51 [22:19:51 DBG] RECEIVE rabbitmq://my-rabbitmq/kafka/my-kafka-topic null Foo.V1.MyMessage Bar.KafkaMyMessageConsumer(00:00:00.0014020)
```

I see that RabbitMQ is associated with the Kafka-Topic somehow; but there where no exchanges created on the RabbitMQ for the Kafka-Topic

My "fix" was to use `AddMassTransit` twice, using a `IKafkaBus` and a `IRabbitMqBus` and calling `busConfigurator.UsingInMemory();` for the Kafka-MassTransit-Integration (that results in similar log messages but with `loopback` uri schemes)

Comment: I just found the documentation about the multi bus. https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/multibus
I think that solves it

Comment: You do _not_ need to use MultiBus, nor should you, in this scenario.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson as always, thanks for your comments, please see my latest edit

Comment: Again, don't use MultiBus. The logs showing rabbitmq are just how the endpoints log, it isn't using RMQ at all.

Answer (score 1):

Consuming from Kafka and RabbitMQ on the same bus instance works perfectly fine, and there is no interaction or exchange of messages between Kafka and RabbitMQ.

I'm not sure what you're suggesting, but your supposition isn't correct. Riders don't use the bus transport at all, for anything.